# Prevent inner table from allowing drop, in jquery ui sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, gridview

I am trying to implement the `jQuery-ui - Sortable` to my ASP.NET Gridview control, but as one of my gridview cells has inner tables, it allows dropping in those inner tables as well. I want it to be droppable in the parent table only, i.e. between GridView's parent rows.

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fvsyfgz3/2/), that'll help see the problem.

`Sortable` is instantiated like this:

```
$().ready(function(){
$("#BodyPlaceHolder_grdManualArrange tbody").sortable({
        cancel: ".di-disabled",
        update: function () {

        },
        handle: ".dragHandle",
        items: "tr",
        opacity: 0.8

    });
    $('#BodyPlaceHolder_grdManualArrange tbody').sortable({ items: 'tr:not(:first)' });// Not allowing the first row (head) to be sorted


    $(".di-disabled-sorting").removeClass("ui-sortable"); // Removing the ui-sortable class from the inner tables
});
```

Here if you drag a row (using the drag-handle in the leftmost row), and try to drop it in between other rows, it'll work fine, but if you try to drop it in between the `top` and `bottom` arrows, the row being sorted, will be dropped there also, which should not be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might help you mate.i haven't tried it,but I think it might to some extend solve your case.Add a before stop property that might help u prevent your current behavior. :)

```
 beforeStop : function (ev, ui) {
            if ($(ui.placeholder).closest(".di-disabled-sorting").size() == 1)                           $(this).sortable('cancel');
        },
```